# How can I programatically click the "compose" button in GMail with greasemonkey?

Tags: javascript, gmail, greasemonkey

I am creating a script for GMail, which requires me to duplicate various links on left side like inbox, all mail, spam and compose. 
I have all the links working except compose. I can't figure out what's going when I click on. You can find my code below. I'd appreciate any help

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           GMC Test
// @namespace      com.pbg
// @description    test
// @include        http*://mail.google.com*
// ==/UserScript==

//loading function
function tryAgain(tries) {
    setTimeout(function() { init(tries++); }, 1000*tries);
}

//gets a node by XPath
function getNodeByXPath(expression, parent) {
   var r = parent.evaluate(expression, parent, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);
   return ((r != null) ? r.iterateNext() : null);
}

//initialize
function init(tries) {

   tries = tries || 0;
   if (tries > 3) return; // give up, too many tries
   // Locate the canvas_frame iframe
   var f = document.getElementById("canvas_frame");
   if (f == null) return tryAgain(tries);
   // Locate the document
   var doc = f.contentWindow.document;
   if (doc == null) return tryAgain(tries);
   // make sure all the links are loaded
   if (getNodeByXPath("//a[contains(@href,'#inbox')]", doc) == null) return tryAgain(tries);

   go();
}
function go() {

   function fireEvent(xPath,event)//https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.dispatchEvent
   {
      var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
      evt.initMouseEvent(event, true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
      var cb = getNodeByXPath(xPath, doc);
      var canceled = !cb.dispatchEvent(evt);
      GM_log("event canceled = " + canceled);
   }
   var doc = document.getElementById("canvas_frame").contentWindow.document;

   //THE LINE BELOW WORKS
   //setTimeout(function(){GM_log("let's click starred!");fireEvent("//a[contains(@href,'#starred')]", "click")}, 5000); 

   //THIS DOENS'T WORK
   setTimeout(function(){GM_log("now let's click compose!");fireEvent("//div[@class='J-Zh-I J-J5-Ji L3')]", "click")}, 5000);
}

window.addEventListener('load', init, false );
```

Comment: I hope you're not asking for help on making a spam generator...

Comment: @PowerUser: Thought the same thing... But Google should be pretty smart to catch bots sending email. 2, you can use GMAIL directly through SMTP. So why would you do that with GreaseMonkey?

Comment: Well, if all you know is GreaseMonkey and you wanted to make a cheap spambot without learning any new languages, then it's one way to go (no matter how inefficient it is).

Comment: The "Compose" button is not a button, nor a link.  It's a div with a whole *mess* of event listeners.  You're probably going to need to sniff out the key functions and call them directly using `unsafeWindow`.  Good luck.

Comment: No, I am not making a spam generator, absolutely not!
I am trying to fix a script I wrote a while ago http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/46938

Comment: Hey Pasha, were you able to find a solution? If so, can you post the code snippet? Don't worry I'm not doing a SPAM bot, I'm working on a custom FF Gmail extension. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the newer AJAX-y style GMail, you could just change the href of the page to the compose url as follows* and just let the page's event handlers trigger/handle the hashtag change as usual:

```
document.location.href = "#compose";
```

Alternatively, if you are using the basic HTML view, you can use xPath to find the compose mail anchor and alter the `document.location.href` to match whatever the link points to.

I'm sure a more elegant/resilient to change xPath can be written but a brief look just now indicates that it has an accesskey attribute set to c which is probably distinctive enough to hunt the correct link:

```
var nodesSnapshot = document.evaluate(
    '//*[@accesskey="c"]', 
     document,
     null,
     XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
     null
  );

document.location.href = nodesSnapshot.snapshotItem(0).href;
```

*nb: both have been tested and are working within the Firebug but might work differently in a Greasemonkey script due to the use of iFrames in the AJAX-y view / other factors etc